# Chopped onions in metal or plastic containers

Tags: storage, onions

Which preserves diced onions better? A plastic or metal container?? I'm trying to figure out which is a better storage container.

Comment: Glass.  Plastic absorbs smells, metal can react chemically.

Answer (score 4):

The key thing to look for is that the container closes as tight as possible. Metal or plastic doesn't matter. However, I would probably use metal or glass, since plastic can absorb some of the flavour of the raw onions. This would then make that container unsuitable for storing other things.

Comment: And I hope that by 'metal' the OP means good stainless steel.  Anything else is likely to react badly with the onion